# alias_method_chain is deprecated - Rails 5 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, deprecated, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm updating my rails app and I need to refactor a method that is using `alias_method_chain` because it is deprecated. The message says to use module#prepend as recommended by Rails 5. Here is the helper that I'm trying to refactor:

```
 module ActiveSupport
  module NumberHelper
    def number_to_delimited_with_unicode_infinity(number, options = {})
      result = number_to_delimited_without_unicode_infinity(number, options)
      result.sub(/^Infinity$/, "∞")
    end
    alias_method_chain :number_to_delimited, :unicode_infinity
  end
end
```

If anyone know how I can refactor with `super` or some other way let me know thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. I don't know why they used `alias_method_chain` to begin with but this gets rid of the deprecation warning with the same functionality.

```
module ActiveSupport
  module NumberHelper
    def number_to_delimited(number, options = {})
      number.to_s.sub(/^Infinity$/, "∞")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case this solution seems to be fine. If you have to have a monkey patch with reference to original method then you can do it creating an alias before patching:

```
module ActiveSupport
  module NumberHelper

    # create alias to original method
    alias :original_number_to_delimited :number_to_delimited

    def number_to_delimited(number, options = {})
      result = original_number_to_delimited(number, options)
      result.sub(/^Infinity$/, "∞")
    end
  end
end
```